# How to access the label variable in QMessageBoxPrivate when extending QMessageBox class?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to extend QMessageBox to set the label's QTextInteractionFlags to Qt::TextSelectableByMouse|Qt::TextSelectableByKeyboard.

I checked the src code of qmessagebox.cpp

```
void QMessageBox::setText(const QString &text)
{
    Q_D(QMessageBox);
    d->label->setText(text);
    d->label->setWordWrap(d->label->textFormat() == Qt::RichText
        || (d->label->textFormat() == Qt::AutoText && Qt::mightBeRichText(text)));
    d->updateSize();
}
```

I sort of need a code like this:

```
void QMessageBox::setTextInteractionFlags ( Qt::TextInteractionFlags flags )
{
    Q_D(QMessageBox);
    d->label->textInteractionFlags(flags);
}
```

So how can i extend QMessageBox and get the d-pointer on QMessageBox? Seems like i need to access the QMessageBoxPrivate class.

Comment: You can't - QMessageBoxPrivate isn't part of the public API. Its symbols might not even be exported (depending the compiler) and it could change completely with the next Qt release (no guarantees made about the stability of private implementation).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I find an object name in 4.8.2 src code. How about using the object name like QLabel * label = msgBox.findChild<QLabel *>("qt_msgbox_label"); to get the label variable?

Comment: hyu163: That might work, but the name could change at any time, with the next Qt version. It probably won't, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Subcalss one of `QStyle` and reimplement styleHint method.

```
#include <QCommonStyle>

class MyStyle : public QCommonStyle
{
public:
    explicit MyStyle() {}
    int styleHint(StyleHint sh, const QStyleOption *opt, const QWidget *widget, QStyleHintReturn *hret) const
    {
        if (SH_MessageBox_TextInteractionFlags == sh)
        {
           return Qt::TextSelectableByMouse | Qt::TextSelectableByKeyboard;
        }
        return QCommonStyle::styleHint(sh, opt, widget, hret);
    }
};
```

Apply your style to the message box.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("This is something text.");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setStyle(new MyStyle);
int ret = msgBox.exec();
```